# Pipeline a -bash en C

Tags: c, pipe

tengo una pregunta acerca del uso que hace el ordenador de un pipeline abierto con el shell bash.
Supongamos que tengo un programa "maestro" #0, y una serie de programas esclavo #1, #2, #3... Y además, el resultado de #1 es usado por #2, el de #2 por #3, y así sucesivamente. Si mi programa #0 abre un pipeline secuencialmente con 1,2,3, etc y los manda correr de una forma como esta:

PROGRAMA #0:

```
...

pipe=popen("bash","w");

fprintf(pipe,"./programa#1 \n");

fprintf(pipe,"./programa#2 \n");

fprintf(pipe,"./programa#3 \n");

.

.

.

...
```

Entonces, ¿cómo gestiona el ordenador el hecho de que se "acumulen" ordenes enviadas a bash? ¿Tiene un buffer? ¿Si después de cada fprintf escribo fflush(pipe), garantizaré que las ordenes llegan al shell en el orden correcto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿cómo gestiona el ordenador el hecho de que se "acumulen" ordenes enviadas a bash?

El *ordenador* no gestiona las órdenes enviadas de ninguna manera. A *bash* le llegan **siempre** las órdenes de forma secuencial y se limita a encadenarlas en... exacto, un buffer interno.

> ¿Tiene un buffer?

Efectivamente, tiene un buffer interno. De cara al programador no es muy diferente a escribir en un fichero.

> ¿Si después de cada fprintf escribo fflush(pipe), garantizaré que las ordenes llegan al shell en el orden correcto?

Con `fflush` únicamente conseguirás forzar el refresco de la consola... los mensajes seguirán llegando en orden aleatorio porque estás trabajando con procesos independientes (programación en paralelo), luego los mensajes se seguirán mostrando mezclados... si llega  a mejorar un poco la presentación será porque, como te he comentado, el refresco de la consola es un proceso costoso que facilita que los procesos se sincronicen ligeramente... pero es una operación que no hace milagros.

Para garantizar un orden concreto tendrás que implementar bloqueos entre los procesos (busca información sobre semáforos y mútex)